# Activate command from onmouseover

Tags: jquery

I have written the following link:

```
<li><a href="#" onmouseover="$("#Layover_1").hide().fadeIn("slow");"
    onmouseout="document.getElementById('#Layover_1').hide()">Layover </a></li>
```

The display on this div is set to none.  I used jsfiddle and the fade works onload there, but I can not get it to work the same in my site.

Thank you.

Comment: Your nested quotes look problematic. Have you included jQuery in your site? Do you see any javascript errors?

Comment: .hide() is a jQuery function and will not work when you use document.getElementById(). also you dont need the `#` in getElementById() only the id inside quotes

Comment: You have improperly nested quotes in your example.  Do you get any errors on your site?  Possibly about `$` not existing?

Comment: I'm concerned with the way you have this set up.  You `.hide()` before  `.fadeIn()` which should make the element fire the `onmouseout` event, which will make the whole thing go away.

Comment: give the link <a href ..... > a class then use the class to identify in a function , that is going to be maintence hell like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problematic nested quotes indeed. You should use single quotes in your `onmouseover` attribute value so that you don't prematurely close your `onmouseover` code:

```
<li><a href="#" onmouseover="$('#Layover_1').hide().fadeIn('slow');"
onmouseout="$('#Layover_1').hide()">Layover </a></li>
```

Also, as mentioned, `document.getElementById` is not jQuery.

Comment: that was just one of the errors in there

Comment: Was typing too fast, edited.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!! That fixed it!  I am sorry.  I thought I had gotten all the javascript out, but obviously I had not.  You are a rockstar!

Comment: @user2034084 Glad to know it worked! I would now suggest looking into and maybe following some of the other best practices and suggestions mentioned in the comments/other answer(s).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using jQuery's [hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/):

```
$('a#the_link').hover(
    function() { $("#Layover_1").stop(true,true).fadeIn("slow"); },
    function() { $("#Layover_1").stop(true,true).hide(); }
);

<li><a href="#" id="the_link">Layover</a></li>
```

[Fiddle with it here](http://jsfiddle.net/jmEmB/)